# Would this quadrilateral-shaped airfoil produce lift with a zero angle of attack?

Tags: wing, lift, airfoil, vtol

I have been recently studying the shapes and characteristics of different high-lift airfoils that have been used for VTOL aircrafts. While studying these different designs today, a particular quadrilateral-shaped airfoil design popped into my mind and I am now very curious to know if this airfoil shape would be ideal as a high-lift airfoil for a VTOL aircraft, either as an airplace wing for a VTOL aircraft, or perhaps as a rotor blade for a high-lift helicopter.

I believe this airfoil should produce lift even though it will have a zero angle of attack as it moves through the air.

Please reference the following drawing:

[image]

It will produce a lot of drag but at the same time I believe that the air pressure differential should produce a lot of lift.

Would this quadrilateral-shaped airfoil produce lift with a zero angle of attack?

**EDIT**

I have changed the main question from 'Would this quadrilateral-shaped airfoil be ideal for VTOL aircraft?' to 'Would this quadrilateral-shaped airfoil produce lift with a zero angle of attack?' because this is really the particular answer that I am seeking.

Comment: _"I believe..."_ - on what basis? Have you put this in a wind tunnel and tested it? Why do you think that the engineers who **have** tested aerofoils haven't come up with this yet?

Comment: @CatchAsCatchCan, I said that because of my interest in VTOL aircrafts and due to my self-study of airfoils and aerodynamics over the past few years. I am actually planning to make a set of blades with this particular design on my 3D printer and install them on my drone to see if it will lift the drone up, but before I do so, I would first like to get some feedback on this design from actual aerodynamic experts.

Comment: Well, in the vertical phase of flight a VTOL aircraft wing has no forward speed, so no lift. Once it has transitioned to horizontal flight a VTOL aircraft is just an aircraft. Beware of [Dunning Kruger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunning%E2%80%93Kruger_effect)

Comment: @user255577: I think you need to clarify something.  By "blades", do you mean the propellors (or rotors?) on the motors?  That's rather different than a wing.

Comment: @CatchAsCatchCan, I understand what you saying and I want to point out that I am not an aviation expert nor do I pretend to be. I just want to know whether this particular airfoil will produce lift while moving through the air with a zero angle of attack.

Comment: @jamesqf, I should have said 'helicopter rotor blades' and 'airplane wings'.

Comment: There are much more efficient, and proven shapes to choose from, why this?!

Comment: @MichaelHall, I have been very interested in finding an airfoil that could lift an aircraft without getting any lift from the deflection of air downwards which almost all airfoils do.

Comment: @user255577, "for every action there is an equal and opposite reaction".  All lift generating airfoils create their upforce by producing a downforce.  This is basic physics.

Comment: @MichaelHall, I understand that law. This airfoil though should still create an upforce since there should be low air pressure above the top surface of the slope of the airfoil -- the area of the airfoil that is at a 45 degree angle. As far as I can see, the air pressure differential between the top and bottom surfaces of the slope section should create an upforce that should lift the airfoil.

Comment: **If** there is a net pressure differential between the top and bottom surface, then there **must** be air deflected downwards. One is equivalent to the other. If you think that your airfoil generates lift, and you do in fact understand Newton's laws, you **know** air is deflected downwards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Draw a line from the leading edge to the trailing edge.  This is the chord, and it has a positive angle of attack as the shape is oriented.  Therefore your premise that this has zero angle of attack is incorrect.

Since you can produce lift with a positive angle of attack using a flat plate, it is reasonable to assume that this shape, as drawn, should produce some amount of lift.  But if oriented so the leading and trailing edges were aligned, (zero AOA) it would not.

However, it will also have tremendous drag, and likely very poor stall characteristics with the sharp corner on the top surface causing premature airflow separation.

There are lots of proven airfoil designs out there.  If this was a good idea someone would have tried it in the last 100 years.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out about the chord line. I guess what I should have written is that the bottom surface of this airfoil will remain parallel with the ground as it moves through the air, or another way of saying it is that the airfoil will always be in the same position as it is shown in the drawing.

Comment: Understood.  Just curious, you admit to not being an aviation expert, so why do you think this design might be a good idea?

Comment: I have to admit that the way I envisioned the air moving around this airfoil was wrong and that this airfoil will not create lift.

Answer (score 1):

Would definitely create some lift if flying supersonic ;)

Otherwise, sharp edges force the flow to detach and thus destroy any lift capabilities of the shape.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will produce lift, just like [*any* body that is asymmetrical w.r.t. the flow field will produce lift.](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/80566/31425)

A program like [XFOIL](https://web.mit.edu/drela/Public/web/xfoil/) can estimate its lift and drag at various angles of attack and at various Reynolds numbers.  If you wanted to convince a professional to build such an airfoil, they'd want such numbers first.

Comment: Do you have a source for the claim that any asymmetric body produces lift? I think it's an interesting claim and would like to know more.

Comment: *Handwavingly*, such a body causes vertical flow, possibly up, possibly down, but not zero;  action-reaction means the body then experiences lift.  *Experimentally*, a flat plate I tested in UIUC's low speed wind tunnel with one face slightly rougher than the other produced lift at AoA=0.  *Mathematically*, you probably could build something pathological where all the lifts and torques cancelled out... I'd love to see such a beast.

Comment: Ah yes, I was especially interested in your last bullet point. I guess the obvious counterexample would be an airplane that is trimmed for level flight in 0g (assuming most airplanes are not fully symmetrical). So I guess [almost all](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_all) asymmetric bodies produce lift.

Comment: So, the Vomit Comet trimmed for hands-off flight during its parabolic segment?  There's still some thrust and drag, but I guess it's as free of lift as a golf ball...

Comment: A [non-rotating](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnus_effect) golf-ball ;)